# how can we run multiple mongodb versions on same system?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, ubuntu-14.04

How can i run mongo 2.6 and mongo 3.0 at the same time on my linux system ?

I need this because i have 2 projects one is working on mongo 2.6 and one is working on mongo 3.0

Any help is appreciated !!

Answer (score 0):

If you really wan to do this, and I recommend you DO NOT, then the best way is to use a container tech, docker can work quite well or LXC or one of the others.

However, do note that there is a high chance that if your sever is in the "cloud" it is already vitualised as it is as such you will constantly be losing power and resources due to sub virtualising everything over and over.

DO NOT put them on the same host without some kind of separation there will be a high chance of resource contention and conflict that tools like `ulimit` just cannot solve (well, technically it could but it will be a hairball).

Comment: hmm okay, i am little worried for upgrade mongodb on current project as i have to use wiredtiger with mongodb on another project

Comment: @chirag.sweng It might be ok, there is only one way to find out if using containers won't hurt you